# Using JComboBox to display in JTable

Tags: java, netbeans, jtable, persistence, jdesktop

I was trying to use a combobox to show  contents in a table.
I wrote the code below, bu nothing displayed in the table.

```java
Integer i = ((Destination) (jComboBox1.getSelectedItem())).getId();
query1 = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT d FROM Dayactivity d WHERE d.id=:Id");
query1.setParameter("Id", i);
java.util.Collection data = query1.getResultList();
list2.clear();
list2.addAll(data);
```

When I changed the code as below it returned data correctly and displayed in the table.

```java
Integer i = ((Destination) (jComboBox1.getSelectedItem())).getId();
query1 = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT d FROM Dayactivity d WHERE d.id=:Id");
query1.setParameter("Id", 2);
java.util.Collection data = query1.getResultList();
list2.clear();
list2.addAll(data);
```

Why It is not working for the first code (i) but works for 2 in second code?

Can somebody help me to solve this, I am new to Java & NetBeans

Comment: debug whether variable "i" returns value.

Comment: Is changing Integer to int possible? The setParameter probably read Integer as a Object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do one of the following:

- Debug the code to see the real value of i:

if i is null then you need to change how you access the selected id of combobox as follows:

```
Integer i = ((Destination) jComboBox1.getSelectedIndex();
```

- You need to check the argument of his method:

  1. query1.setParameter(String, int); or
  2. query1.setParameter(String, Integer);

Answer (score 0):

Change how `i` is initialized to:

`int i = jComboBox1.getSelectedIndex();`